# Combinations Inside Combinations

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment

I want to write the binomial coefficient C(C(a, b), C(c, d)) in the notation:
[image].

So I tried `\binom{\binom{a}{b}}{\binom{c}{d}}`.
But, the parentheses were small, like:
[image].

My question: How do I make the parentheses big in order match the inner height?

Also, I have if I have 5 or 6 values such as the one above, how do I put them equally spaced in a line? Is there any better way to arrange these values?

Comment: Don't ask more than one question in one post.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use such a big object inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already busting the line height (`\baselineskip`) with a `\binom`, you might as well just fix it with a `\displaystyle`.

Spacing can be accomplished, inline, with `\hfill`s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\binom{\binom{a}{b}}{\binom{c}{d}}\]
$\binom{\binom{a}{b}}{\binom{c}{d}}$
$\displaystyle\binom{\binom{a}{b}}{\binom{c}{d}}$

\noindent$\displaystyle
\binom{\binom{a}{b}}{\binom{c}{d}}\hfill
\binom{\binom{a}{b}}{\binom{c}{d}}\hfill
\binom{\binom{a}{b}}{\binom{c}{d}}\hfill
\binom{\binom{a}{b}}{\binom{c}{d}}\hfill
\binom{\binom{a}{b}}{\binom{c}{d}}\hfill
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, you didn't answer my second question, which was how to align these in a row, such that these are equally spaced.

Comment: No stacking things on top of other things here? ;-)

Comment: @lil'mathematician Please see my edit.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am a little off my game today.

Answer (score 1):

Applying a new macro `\combcomb` which uses `\genfrac` in the background (which is the basics behind `\binom`)

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{mathtools}


\newcommand{\combcomb}[4]{%
  \genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{0}{\binom{#1}{#2}}{\binom{#3}{#4}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\combcomb{a}{b}{c}{d}$ $\combcomb{e}{f}{g}{h}$

\end{document}
```

[image]